# how to update data of only selected value from v-for loop of array in vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I have created a table which display the product Price, Quantity, Cost, Total If quantity is changed for any product in the table row the value of total also have to update according to the formula quantity * cost. The products array contains cost and name.Everything is working fine but what i don't know is if i am changing quantity of one product all the products in v-for loop getting affected and all products quantity is changing, instead of this how can i change quantity for only updated product and I provided default quantity value as 0 for all products hence only products with more than 0 quantity i can use for my further operations

```
## Html Code ## 
<table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>S.No#</td>
              <td>Product</td>
              <td>Cost</td>
              <td>Quantity</td>
              <td>Total</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="p in products">
              <td>1</td>
              <td>{{p.item}}</td>
              <td>{{p.cost}}</td>
              <td><input type="number" class="form-control qty-box" name="" v-model='qty'></td>
              <td>{{p.cost*qty}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
## Vue Js code ##
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      counter:8,
      qty:0,
      products:[
      {'item':'timber','cost':250,'id':1},
      {'item':'wood','cost':240,'id':2},
      {'item':'primer','cost':120,'id':3},
      {'item':'plywood','cost':360,'id':4},
      {'item':'marker','cost':220,'id':5},
      {'item':'roughwood','cost':480,'id':6},

      ],
      msg: 'Counter',
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: please create live demo or snippet for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow my example in [codepen](https://codepen.io/Maxim222/pen/KBRdjX?editors=1010) or the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="app" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>S.No#</td>
          <td>Product</td>
          <td>Cost</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="p in products">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>{{p.item}}</td>
          <td>{{p.cost}}</td>
          <td><input type="number" class="form-control qty-box" name="" v-model='p.qt'></td>
          <td>{{p.cost*p.qt}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
vue = new Vue({
 el: "#app",
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      counter:8,
      products:[
      {'item':'timber','cost':250,'id':1, 'qt':1},
      {'item':'wood','cost':240,'id':2, 'qt':1},
      {'item':'primer','cost':120,'id':3, 'qt':1},
      {'item':'plywood','cost':360,'id':4, 'qt':1},
      {'item':'marker','cost':220,'id':5, 'qt':1},
      {'item':'roughwood','cost':480,'id':6, 'qt':1},

      ],
      msg: 'Counter',
    }
  }
});
```

**A little suggestion:** Personally, I think, using `v-text` in `HTML` with `Vue` is better than brackets because when using brackets the page will show those before vue parses it which isn't very pretty. IMHO.

Comment: Notice that I've added `qt` parameter to all of your products. Also, see my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't use one number for all rows.

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>S.No#</td>
              <td>Product</td>
              <td>Cost</td>
              <td>Quantity</td>
              <td>Total</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="p in products">
              <td>1</td>
              <td>{{p.item}}</td>
              <td>{{p.cost}}</td>
              <td><input type="number" class="form-control qty-box" name="" v-model='p.qty'></td>
              <td>{{p.cost*p.qty}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

So instead of v-model='qty' use **v-model='p.qty'** and also instead of this `{{p.cost*qty}}` use `{{p.cost*p.qty}}`

Answer (score 0):

Add quantity to each product. You have one quantity value for all products now.

Comment: i have used only one quantity value because the products are iterated by v-for loop